# Solspace User ignoring member/group parameters

Tags: solspace, solspace-user, parameters

When using member_id and group_id parameters in exp:user:xxx tag pairs, the specified group_id or member_id parameter is being ignored and outputs data for the logged in user.
Why is this happening and how do I force User to recognise what I need it to?

EDIT: found out the reason. I'd inadvertently nested 2 exp:user:xxx pairs. Un-nesting them cured it. Surprise.

Comment: what does your tag code look like?

Comment: See edit above. This has been resolved, thanks.